# Where should the tlp configuration file be found?

Tags: tlp

I have installed `tlp` months ago, and the file configuration is in home folder. I don't know the install steps anymore, so I'm asking you guys if it's ok if that configuration file stays there, or should be moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default install puts the config in `/etc/tlp.conf`.

Comment: I don't know why the config is into my home folder, thanks

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, please mark it as such to help other people find the answer faster(because it will be shown as solved).

Comment: It's alright, it looks like I have the config in /etc/default/tlp too, with the same settings, I wonder why is it in Home folder too, with a lock on it.

Comment: The lock means you don’t have permissions to edit it.

Comment: can i delete it?

Comment: Do it through the terminal. You may need sudo.

Answer (score 4):

Since tlp 1.3, the previous default directory for the configuration file `/etc/default` has been replaced by `/etc`.
So **you will find the file as `/etc/tlp.conf` rather than `/etc/default/tlp`.**

Source : [article on Linux Uprising website](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/02/tlp-13-linux-laptop-battery-extender.html) .

Still, if you can't find it just search the file in file manager in the root directory (only for read purpose - can't guarantee whether editing will change the configuration if found in non-default directory. But still you can try and test).