# Ubuntu 18.04 Usb audio device suspended

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm getting some weird problems with my usb soundcard. It is a fiio e10k that works but if i stop playing audio for more that 3 secs, pactl shows the device as suspended

```
gerardo@gerardo-K53SD:~$ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED 
3   alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

I have to unplug the device and plug it in to made it work again.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

## For Ubuntu 16.04+

### Install TLP and list USB Devices

The port for your sound device is auto-suspended when it is idle. The TLP package is the easiest way to manage this. Use these commands:

```
sudo apt install tlp
sudo lsusb
```

> `tlp` may all ready be installed in which case you will see:

```
tlp is already the newest version (0.8-1).
```

> `lsusb` will list all your USB devices:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1bcf:2b8c Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e301 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 187c:0528 Alienware Corporation 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 413c:9016 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0764:0501 Cyber Power System, Inc. CP1500 AVR UPS
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f9:024a Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### Find your specific USB device

Find your sound device in the output. For example my wireless keyboard/mouse is:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

The important details here are the **Manufacturer's ID** followed by a `:` and then the **Model Number**. So I want `046d:c52b`. Find the equivalent for your sound device.

### Blacklist your USB device from auto-suspending

Open the TLP configuration file using `gedit`:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

Search for these lines in the middle of the file:

```
# Exclude listed devices from USB autosuspend (separate with spaces).
# Use lsusb to get the ids.
# Note: input devices (usbhid) are excluded automatically (see below)
#USB_BLACKLIST="1111:2222 3333:4444"
```

In my configuration file I have nothing blacklisted. A line beginning with `#` is a comment and ignored in all configuration files. Note it says **`(usbhid) are excluded automatically**.`hid` stands for Human Interface Device which includes my keyboard and mouse but excludes your sound device.

So we want to add your sound device to the file. Insert the line immediately below the four listed above:

```
USB_BLACKLIST="046d:c52b"
```

**IMPORTANT**: Change `046d:c52b` representing my keyboard/mouse to what you found for your sound device.

Now save the configuration file, exit `gedit`, save all your work and reboot.

Credit: [How can I disable usb-autosuspend for a specific device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device/370406)

Comment: The file /etc/default/tlp is empty on my system. Is there maybe another place where configuration can be located? I'm using Ubuntu 18.

Comment: @Sirhennihau The first line output by `tlp-stat -s` lists your version number. Mine is version `0.8` what is yours?

Comment: For anybody wondering, the configuration file is now located at `/etc/tlp.conf` (source: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251167/955071)).