# Setting up usb audio link with amplifier

Tags: 20.04, audio-player

I followed the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064456/ubuntu-18-04-usb-audio-device-suspended) in order to set up a USB connection to my amp. It worked! But when l disconnected the standard phono link with the amp, it stopped working. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Any tips?

Comment: We will need to know much more about your setup, both hardware and software. Also, what exactly is the problem? If something stops working when you disconnect X, then don't disconnect X.

Comment: I followed the steps in the link cited above, which enabled my PC to recognise the USB link to my amplifier. It just happens to be a Moon amp, but the instructions to recognise the link would be the same process for any USB connection. Previously I listened to music via a phono link from my PC to amp, but that's not necessary now, What I don't understand is why an entirely different connection should affect another connection i.e. why does disconnecting a phono link cut out a USB link?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem by installing pulseaudio. That enabled me to select the amp. Everything working fine now!